# The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated

Tags: c#, email, ssl

I want to send emails using C# for an MVC project and hotmail, I have tried port 25 and 587, using my own credentials, but every time I get '5.7.3 user not authenticated', if I change SSL to false, then I get '5.7.0, Must issue a STARTTLS command first'.
There are 2 other questions with the same problem but one of the answers is old (points me to a setting that doesn't exist in outlook.com) and the other one didn't solve it (changing ssl to false).

This is my code (of course I removed my email and password), question is, what else can I do to get ride of the 5.7.3, am I missing something?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(<email>, <email>);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");

        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(<email>, <pass>);
        mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
        mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code Works normally on my computer!**

There are two issues that you should look at:

- If you enabled the use of external applications in hotmail
- Check the https://account.microsoft.com/account link if your computer
  is locked.

**My code:**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from", "to");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password");

client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

mail.Subject = "test";
mail.Body = "test";

client.Send(mail);
```